# Conversion XmlNode.InnerText to Double

Tags: c#, xml

The condition Double.TryParse(node.ChildNodes[4].InnerText, out course) doesn't work. It's always return 0.

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in XmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ValCurs/Valute"))  
                {
                    if (node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText == curr_name) // CharCode
                    {
                       // throw new Exception(node.ChildNodes[4].InnerText);  //returns 2.085 but the next condition doesn't work
                        if (Double.TryParse(node.ChildNodes[4].InnerText, out course)) // course value, nominal = 100
                        {     
                            if (Int32.Parse(node.ChildNodes[2].InnerText) == 10) course *= 10;   //for RUB, BYR nominal = 10
                            if (Int32.Parse(node.ChildNodes[2].InnerText) == 1000) course /= 10; //for JPY, HUF nominal = 1000
                            return course;
                        }
                    }
```

XML fragment

```
<Valute id="1">
<NumCode>036</NumCode>
<CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
<Nominal>100</Nominal>
<Name>Australian dollars</Name>
<Value>1276.6300</Value>
</Valute>
```

Comment: Always describe "doesn't work". Also, post the XML fragement.

Comment: Side note: accessing child nodes with [1] etc is very brittle. What will happen when the order changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TryParse method uses the current culture thus the number formats might differ depending on you system.

You can use the override version of TryParse where you pass IFormatProvider as a parameter. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture uses . as a decimal separator:

```
Double.TryParse(node.ChildNodes[4].InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out course)
```

Btw. checking values by throwing them as exceptions is rather interesting approach, but I highly recommend debugging/logging to check what is happening.

Comment: Why should the poster "try" this? Code only answers are not usually acceptable here. Please [edit] to provide information regarding how this fixes the problem.